# Disabling sound in a video

Tags: android, video, media-player, preferences

Hi I'm new to android development and working on a game. I currently have an opening cutsceen which is a videoview, but I want to mute the the sound, if the user selects mute music from the preference menu. The problem is I don't know how to mute the music in a videoview without actually turning off the video entirely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is use [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) to mute the music stream at the beginning of the cut scene and unmute it once it is done: VideoView does not provide independent mute controls.

Answer (score 18):

The AudioManager is not a good option always, because you mute all the system...

if you want to get access to the MediaPlayer of a VideoView you have to call MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener and MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, then you can call setVolume(0f, 0f); function to set the volume to 0.

Do this:

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

  VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.VVSimpleVideo);
  MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
  mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
  mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
  videoView.setMediaController(mc);
  String _path = "/mnt/sdcard/Movies/video5.mp4";

  videoView.setVideoPath(_path);
  videoView.setOnPreparedListener(PreparedListener);

  videoView.requestFocus();

  //Dont start your video here
  //videoView.start();


}

MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener PreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){

     @Override
     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer m) {
         try {
                if (m.isPlaying()) {
                    m.stop();
                    m.release();
                    m = new MediaPlayer();
                }
                m.setVolume(0f, 0f);
                m.setLooping(false);
                m.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
     }
 };
```

Comment: This isn't a good option for low API, Media Controller request 21 and a lot of app's using lower API then this.

Comment: @LamaTo - What do you mean by "low API" and "request 21"?

Comment: @Jaydev - API level 21 is for android 5.0 and above. see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) for more info

Comment: @LamaTo I believe you're confusing the MediaController being used.  This is android.widget.MediaController, which is available since API 1, not  android.media.session.MediaController, which was added in API 21.  That's the problem with poor naming :/