# How To Mute Sound Video in VideoView Android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I want Mute Sound of video and use Videoview for playing video

```
   _player.setVideoURI("/sdcard/Movie/byern.mp4");
   _player.start();
```

Now,How can Resolve it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float, float)

Answer (score 2):

You can custom **VideoView** like that

```
    public class VideoPlayer extends VideoView implements OnPreparedListener, OnCompletionListener, OnErrorListener {
        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

        public Player(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
            super(context, attributes);
           //init player
            this.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            this.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            this.setOnErrorListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            this.mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int what, int extra) {  }

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) { ... }

        public void mute() {
            this.setVolume(0);
        }

        public void unmute() {
            this.setVolume(100);
        }

        private void setVolume(int amount) {
            final int max = 100;//change 100 to zeo
            final double numerator = max - amount > 0 ? Math.log(max - amount) : 0;
            final float volume = (float) (1 - (numerator / Math.log(max)));

            this.mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call **MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener** and **MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener** of you want to use **VideoView** .Then you can make **setVolume** method public so that volume can be controlled outside of the scope of the class.Below 3 will solve these..

- [Disabling sound in a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771350/disabling-sound-in-a-video)
- [Mute a playing video by VideoView in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435275/mute-a-playing-video-by-videoview-in-android-application)
- [Muting a video in a VideoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394876/muting-a-video-in-a-videoview)